# jQuery play and stop jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function, var

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ub3wk/65/)

I'm trying to stop a function that starts after the page loads from working by pressing a button and then re activating it by pressing another, so far I can reactivate it but I cannot make the stop button from working with my current code.

```
<button class="play">play</button>
<button class="pause">pause</button>
<div class="scanner-laser">blinking</div>

var blink = (function blink() { 
   var f = $('.scanner-laser').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, blink); 
})();

$(".play").click(function() {
  $('.scanner-laser').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, blink); 
});

$(".pause").click(function() {
    f.stop();
    blink.die();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var f = '';
var blink = (function blink() {
  f = $('.scanner-laser').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, blink);
})();

$(".play").click(function() {
  $('.scanner-laser').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, blink);
});
$(".pause").click(function() {
  f.stop();
  blink.die();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="play">play</button>
<button class="pause">pause</button>
<div class="scanner-laser">blinking</div>
```